# BarLegend for custom colour function

Tags: plotting, color, legending

How do I change this code so the desired `BarLegend` is displayed?

```
color[x_] := Blend[{Black, RGBColor[1, 0, 0, 0.2], Red}, x];
BarLegend[color]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
BarLegend[{color[#] &, {0, 1}}]
```

[image]